# stackoverflow technology to push message?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, websocket, push-notification

when I have a notification in my top menu appear a small icon, now I'm trying to figure out how SOF do that. I think it could be using AJAX that check the server every second, that make sense, but with 1000+ user it will overload the servers I think, can someone tell me if I am right, and let me know how can I use a technology like SOF with a live push without breaking the server

Comment: Look into the concept of [AJAX Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) - I have seen implementations do many thousands of connections with comet pushing (using some very high performance networking libs).

Comment: There's also [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) which can be used for things like chat and updating stock tickers -- it acts like a continuous connection.

Comment: is there any technology that works in IE too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into using [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) technology. It will work with most recent browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and will allow server to push changes to the browser. It's not supported by Internet Explorer, however, so for that browser Ajax polling is pretty much the only option.

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) Please write a full answer, instead of just providing a link.

Comment: thanks, it looks like IE 10 will supported, http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Event Source, unlike AJAX Comet, there is no long held open connection so you're much more capable of handing more clients.

```
/* Event Source Code */
// Initial Startup
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource('EventSource.php');
    // Native EventSource Events
    source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        // Connection was opened.
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            // Connection was closed.
        }
    }, false);
    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        // You'll have to make your own banner function here.
        // e.data, this is what you'll need.
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: how does it works?, can you explain a little bit more about it?